# Generating Pythagorean Triples using Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: java, math, fibonacci

I'm using the Fibonacci sequence to generate some pythagorean triples (3, 4, 5, etc) based off  this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples starting at "Generalized Fibonacci Sequence".

```
public static int fib(int n) {
        if(n == 0) return 0;
        if(n <= 2) return 1;
        int i = 1;
        int temp = 0;

        while(n != 1) {
            i += temp;
            temp = i - temp;
            n--;
        }

        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 4; //a(3)
        int b = 3; //b(3)
        int c = 5; //c(3)

        for(int n = 4; n < 10; n++) {
            System.out.println(a + "^2 + " + b + "^2 = " + c + "^2");
            a = a + b + c;
            b = fib((2 * n) - 1) - b;
            c = fib(2 * n);
        }  
    }
```

However, the output my program is giving me is not accurate:

```
4^2 + 3^2 = 5^2
12^2 + 10^2 = 21^2
43^2 + 24^2 = 55^2
122^2 + 65^2 = 144^2
331^2 + 168^2 = 377^2
876^2 + 442^2 = 987^2
```

What could be causing this problem? Have I been duped by Wikipedia?

Comment: Note that that Wikipedia formula specifies F_1 = 0 and F_2 = 1; you have F_1 = 1 and F_2 = 1.

Comment: You're completely right! I was assuming it was following the standard, but I guess not! Thanks! @MarkDickinson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MarkDickinson pointed out that the formula required F(1) = 0 and F(2) = 1, which is different from what is widely used, where F(1) = 1 and F(2) = 1. That fixed my problem!

Comment: Accept your answer too!

Comment: There's a time restriction! (3 days after you post an answer for yourself) @shekharsuman